# MAMP mysqlnd driver missing

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

Good day people,

I'm using MAMP as Apache/MYSQL Server and for some reason the mysqlnd driver is missing or bugged.  So now i can't use functions like `get_result();` Is there someone who can tell me how to fix this ?

Thanks!